# Trying to make a password using an array with arduino

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I am a beginner to using the arduino and I'm stuck at a certain problem. What I have is a programm that prints numbers to the console with the press of a button. What I'm trying to get is to the point that I enter 4 numbers after which it checks if it is the same as an array of numbers that I set before.
Now the problem is that I dont know how to make the programm check if the array I entered with the buttons is the same as the one I wrote before.

```
int b1 = 4;
int bs1 = 0;
int b2 = 2;
int bs2 = 0;
int b3 = 3;
int bs3 = 0;
int count = 0;
int correctcode[] = {2,3,3,1}; 
int code[4];

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(greenPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(redPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (b1, INPUT);
  pinMode (b2, INPUT);
  pinMode (b3, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
 bs1 = digitalRead(b1);
 bs2 = digitalRead(b2);
 bs3 = digitalRead(b3);

 if (bs1 == HIGH) {
  count++;
  Serial.print ("1");
  delay(500);
  if (count == 4){
    Serial.println ("pincode ingevoerd, checking....");

  }

 }
 if (bs2 == HIGH) {
  count++;
  Serial.print ("2");
  delay(500);
  if (count == 4){
    Serial.println ("pincode ingevoerd, checking....");
  }
 }
 if (bs3 == HIGH) {
  count++;
  Serial.print ("3");
  delay(500);
if (count == 4){
    Serial.println ("pincode ingevoerd, checking....");
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Please look into the [subscript operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/subscript-operator?view=vs-2019) and how [while](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_while_loop.htm) and [for](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_for_loop.htm) loops work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Button pins ( with external pulldown resistors )
const byte b1 = 4;
const byte b2 = 2;
const byte b3 = 3;

// Signal pins
const byte greenPin = 12;
const byte redPin = 13; 

byte count = 0; // 0 ... 4 counted button presses
byte correctcode[4] = {2,3,3,1}; 
byte code[4];

void setup() {
  pinMode(greenPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(redPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (b1, INPUT);
  pinMode (b2, INPUT);
  pinMode (b3, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
 bool bs1 = digitalRead(b1);
 bool bs2 = digitalRead(b2);
 bool bs3 = digitalRead(b3);

 if (bs1) add(1);
 else if (bs2) add(2);
 else if (bs3) add(3);
}

 void add( byte value ) {
    Serial.print (value);
    code[count++] = value; 
    if (count == 4) {
       count=0;
       if (check()) correct();
       else         wrong();
    }
    else
       delay(500);
 }

 bool check() {
    for (byte i=0; i < 4; i++) {
       if (code[i] != correctcode[i]) {
         return false; 
       }
    }
    return true;
 }

 void wrong() {
     Serial.println(" -> wrong !");  
     digitalWrite(redPin, HIGH);
     delay(1000); 
     digitalWrite(redPin, LOW);
 }

 void correct() {
     Serial.println(" -> correct !");  
     digitalWrite(greenPin, HIGH);
     delay(300); 
     digitalWrite(greenPin, LOW);
 }
```

*Compiled, but  Untested*

Don't duplicate code, but create functions. This can make code easier to read.

If you do not want an autorepeat ( after 500 ms ) for your buttons, better check for state changes (Pressed -> Released)

If multiple buttons are pressed, I added a priority. You might want to discard that state instead.

For more than 3 buttons, read about arrays :)